# How to convert images to a video by the time they have been taken/saved and not by name?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a Livestream that takes pictures every one or two seconds. Then I have a folder in which the pictures are being saved. 
Usually I would just simply take `ffmpeg -start_number -i IMG_%d.JPG video.webm` (I need the end format in .webm). I want to use the saved pictures to form a time-lapse to put up next to the stream. So people can see the last 24h/ 7d and 90d. So I wondered if I could code that all the pics of that time period are used and only them. 
I later want it to happen automatic, so i dont have to write the code new every day.

Thanks for your help

Comment: look into using the filesystem to help organize the input to the process of daily iteration..  ie if each webm is to cover 24 hrs, then rotate to new directory on same time interval.  Have a dispatch function that  reconciles output from the webcam to input reqmts for how u choose to organize the ffmpeg input

Comment: Sure, you can write code to do almost anything. What exactly do you need help with doing?

Comment: Thanks unfortunate i cant change the saving system of the camera. Thanks anyway i‘ll find another way.